# How to remove a class of all element expect one in one Array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am learning Vanilla JS and DOM. Today I have a problem when I want to remove a class of all elements expect one.

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
  function toggleOpen() {
    this.classList.toggle("open");
    console.log(panels);
  }
  function toggleActive(e) {
    if (e.propertyName.includes("flex")) {
      this.classList.toggle("open-active");
    }
  }

  panels.forEach((panel) => panel.addEventListener("click", toggleOpen));
  panels.forEach((panel) =>
    panel.addEventListener("transitionend", toggleActive)
  );
```

I want when I click "panel" the only panel be clicked have class "open" and remove all class "open" of all another "panel". (Exactly I want only a panel to have class "open" in all time, and it can toggle.) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toggleOpen`, iterate over all panels (except this one) and remove their `open` class first:

```
function toggleOpen() {
  // Close all other panels:
  for (const panel of panels) {
    if (panel !== this) {
      panel.classList.remove('open');
    }
  }
  // Either open this panel or close it:
  this.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Now i know "this" can be use like that.